Convert wide table into long for a set of column
Current data in sheet attached looks like this:



SERIAL
NAME
CITY1
TOWN1
CITY2
TOWN2
CITY3
TOWN3




1
Name1
cityA
townA
cityB
townY
cityD
townX


2
Name2
cityA
townA
cityC
townZ




3
Name3
cityC
townC






4
Name4
cityC
townC







I need to copy this data in a new sheet in below format:



SERIAL
NAME
CITY
TOWN




1
Name1
cityA
townA


1
Name1
cityB
townY


1
Name1
cityD
townX


2
Name2
cityA
townA


2
Name2
cityC
townZ


3
Name3
cityC
townC


4
Name4
cityC
townC



I tried below formula for each column:

Serial: =ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(currentdata!A2&"^",counta(currentdata!C2,currentdata!E2,currentdata!G2)),"^")))
Name: =ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(currentdata!B2&"^",counta(currentdata!C2,currentdata!E2,currentdata!G2)),"^")))
City: =ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(FILTER({currentdata!C2,currentdata!E2,currentdata!G2},LEN({currentdata!C2,currentdata!E2,currentdata!G2}))))
Town: =ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(FILTER({currentdata!D2,currentdata!F2,currentdata!H2},LEN({currentdata!D2,currentdata!F2,currentdata!H2}))))

It works for 1 row only. However, when I try to expand to all rows, it doesn't work.
Below is the link to sample file where first sheet has current data and second sheet has the format of what it needs to be. And third sheet has formula for 1 row.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K-whYc5boxi6qpqR3V-kVBNo6SYNxYoC9nQDJSzS_Yo/edit?usp=drivesdk

Your sheet gives me 'Access denied'

You should be able to access it now

You can unpivot a "wide" table into a "tall" table with string concatenation and split(), but that exposes you to the risk of converting values like "1 2" into dates, and converting numbers in custom formats into text strings. To avoid that, use this generalized pattern:
=let( 
  unpivot_, lambda(data, numFixedCols, numColsPerGroup, let(k,n(numFixedCols),d,if(k,data,hstack(sequence(rows(data)),data)),f,if(k,k,1),g,numColsPerGroup,s,lambda(r,c,h,w,chooserows(choosecols(d,sequence(1,w,c)),sequence(h,1,r))),h,hstack(s(1,1,1,f),"Label",s(1,f+1,1,g)),i,sequence(1,(columns(d)-f)/g,f+1,g),a,reduce(h,sequence(rows(d)-1,1,2),lambda(a,r,let(x,s(r,1,1,f),b,reduce(tocol(æ,2),i,lambda(y,c,let(z,s(r,c,1,g),if(""=+z,y,vstack(y,hstack(x,s(1,c,1,1),z)))))),vstack(a,b)))),if(k,a,choosecols(a,sequence(1,columns(a)-1,2))))), 

  unpivot_(Sheet1!A1:H, 2, 2) 
)

To vary the number of "fixed" columns, replace the first 2 with the true number of common columns. To vary the number of "repeated" columns, replace the second 2.
The output will include a Label column that indicates which group of columns repeated columns were read from as in city1, city2 or city3. To leave out that indicator, use this:
  table, unpivot_(Sheet1!A1:H, 2, 2), 
  choosecols(table, 1, 2, 4, 5) 

See lambda().

Thanks but gives me an error. I have rephrased the question as suggested by Luuk.

The formula gets a table that exactly matches your desired result. If you need help inserting the formula, Insert > Sheet in the sample spreadsheet and put the formula in cell A1 of the new sheet to show what kind of trouble you have.

With the following data:



SERIAL
NAME
CITY1
TOWN1
CITY2
TOWN2
CITY3
TOWN3




1
one
1-city1
1-town1
2-city2
2-town2
3-city3
3-town3


2
two
2-city1
2-town1


2-city3
2-town3


3
three
3-city1
3-town1
3-city2
3-town2
3-city3
3-town3



You can put the headers in row 7
and this function in A8:
{ QUERY(A2:H4,"SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE (C<>'')",-1); 
  QUERY(A2:H4,"SELECT A, B, E, F WHERE (E<>'')",-1);  
  QUERY(A2:H4,"SELECT A, B, G, H WHERE (G<>'')",-1) }

This will result in 1 list of the return values from those 3 QUERY() functions, resulting in:



SERIAL
NAME
CITY
TOWN




1
one
1-city1
1-town1


2
two
2-city1
2-town1


3
three
3-city1
3-town1


1
one
2-city2
2-town2


3
three
3-city2
3-town2


1
one
3-city3
3-town3


2
two
2-city3
2-town3


3
three
3-city3
3-town3



